# Best practices for deploying Spark application that uses a message broker

Tags: java, apache-spark, emr, messagebroker

I have created a Java application that uses message broker messages to start Spark jobs, based on parameters that are send in the message. I want to deploy the applocation on a Spark cluster (AWS EMR). To do so I was thinking of using `spark-submit` with the uber jar containing my application. The problem with this method is that I will have a problem deploying new versions. I will have to remove the application from the Spark cluster and submit the new version. Is there a way to do this? Is there a better method to use a message broker inside a Spark application?

Comment: most deployments of things seem to be so custom that there isn't a best practice. Too many factors & changing requirements..

Comment: Yes,  but this seemed like an often use case,  so I thought that there would be a good way to do it.